# Python find closest decimal match

Tags: python, django, django-models, decimal

I have a list as follows:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('8.25', '0'),
    ('7.35', '1'),
    [...]
)
```

The model I use stores the first value in the tuple (e.g. 8.25 -incidentally, in mm). I need a function that takes any given decimal value (potentially not in the list) and matches it with the closest value on the CHOICES list, to return the relevant whole number.

So example input could be `8.11` which would return `0` or `7.30` which would return `1` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your values are sorted and assuming the number of the choices is not huge:

```
result = sorted([(math.abs(k - input_val),v) for (k,v) in choices])[0]
```

Otherwise sort the choices once and use binary search ([bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html)), as suggested in other answer. It'd look like:

```
#do this part only once
choices_dict = dict(choices)
sorted_keys = sorted([ float(k) for (k,v) in choices])
#...
l,r = bisect_left(input_value,sorted_keys), bisect_right(input_value,sorted_keys)
k = l if math.abs(input_value-l)<math.abs(input_value-r) else r
result = choices_dict(str(k))
```

Comment: A small point, but the first element of each tuple in the OP's example is a string, so you need `float(k)` instead of `k` when subtracting the input value

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html

Read the examples at the end.

Comment: Yay for `bisect`, but I'm not sure it will answer the OP's question: he wants the nearest, whereas bisect will give the first one that's smaller.

Comment: The word "closest" is not **fully** defined in the question.  Maybe it means "closest without being larger".  That's my hope.  Otherwise the answer is wrong.

Comment: Bisect will land you next to two closest approximations: the one that's smaller and the one that's bigger. Then you can make an obvious choice between the two.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well

```
distances = [ (abs(target-float(v)), m) for v,m in CHOICES ]
value, match = min( distances )
```

Since you use the word, "decimal", perhaps you mean this.

```
distances = [ (abs(target-decimal.Decimal(v)), m) for v,m in CHOICES ]
```

Not that it matters much.